# How to get weather information from google based on date

Tags: javascript, weather, google-weather-api

Today I started a simple Application,Using this App user can find the weather information based on date.So I want to use an third party library I searched in google.Finally I found `Google` provides the `weather` information through api calls

In my application,their is no any maps.I just want to show weather information from response.

If user pick any date form calendar for example user pics `2014-01-29`, I want to display weather information next two days like (`2014-01-29,2014-01-30,2014-01-31`).So some dates might be comes in `history` and some dates might be comes in `future`.

I don't know,whether `google` supports or not as per my cases.but I hope it supports.So I searched in `google`and founded I need to add the following code in my `index.html` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather&sensor=false">
</script>
```

If it is possible,can anyone suggest me with a simple example.I just want to response.Once I get the response I will fetch data which was I need and show to user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Google weather supports historical data, but have you looked at all at the Forecast.io API (https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2)?